# Jquery - Insert text before gmail signature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gmail

I'm building a utility base on [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/), that inserts text at the end of your email (but before the signature). InboxSDK gives you the message body as an HTML Element, and I'm trying to use some Jquery to place the text. Where it gets complicated, is the different 'types' of signatures a user could potentially have. I've grouped them into 3.

1. No Signature
2. '--' Signature
3. NO '--' Signature

2 and 3 are the difficult ones. This is the HTML in both cases.

2.

```
<div id=":nv" class="Am Al editable LW-avf" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 309px;">
    <br clear="all">
    <div>
        <!--
            <div>
              Injected Text
            </div>
        -->
        <br>
    </div>--
    <br>
    <div class="gmail_signature" data-smartmail="gmail_signature">
        <!-- Signature Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

3.

```
<div id=":nv" class="Am Al editable LW-avf" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 309px;">
<br clear="all">
<div>
    <!--
        <div>
          Injected Text
        </div>
    -->
    <div class="gmail_signature" data-smartmail="gmail_signature">
        <!-- Signature Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

When the '--' exists, I'd like for the new text `<div>` I'm injecting to be placed within the first child div. When it doesn't exist I want it as an immediate child of the Message Body, one div before the signature.

What's the most elegant, *jquer-ish* way to perform this?

[Gmail Signature Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Dxj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it.

```
var insertDiv = $(`<div>${text}</div>`);
var emailBody = window.gmailComposer.getBodyElement();

if( $('[data-smartmail="gmail_signature"]').length > 0 ) { //if there is indeed a signature block.
  if ( $(emailBody).children().has('[data-smartmail="gmail_signature"]').length == 0 ) { //if we have 'double dash' mode enabled.
    insertDiv.insertAfter($('[aria-label="Message Body"] > div:not(\'[data-smartmail="gmail_signature"]\'):last'), emailBody); //insert the text in the last div before the "--" div
  } else { //'double dash' mode disabled
    insertDiv.insertBefore($('[data-smartmail="gmail_signature"]'), emailBody); //insert the text before the signature
  }
} else { //no signature
  $(emailBody).append(insertDiv); //insert the text at the end of the email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the jQuery `prepend()` in order to append as first child, and the `before()/insertBefore()` in order to add before an element?

Here the links to the doc:

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: I'm aware of those functions, I suppose I'm more after a way of identifying which case is presented, and then apply the appropriate JQ function.

Comment: Put an id to your main container, the one which will be filled with the content. 
Then look for the element in this way:
`if ($( "#myDiv divExpected" ).length > 0) // use prepend because the element exists
else // use before because the element doesn't exist`

Comment: In both cases (2 and 3) the signature exists. So your suggestion unfortunately doesn't disambiguate.

Comment: How about this wording.

"How can I tell if the signature is a child, or grandchild of the main container?"

That will offer me the case that's presented.

Comment: You can use the `$(element).children().length` or  `$(element).parents().length` to get the current depth of an element. 
Can you please paste the returned structure in both cases? It should be easier to understand what you get and how to achieve your goal

Comment: I posted a solution that's handled all three cases. What's SO etiquette for acknowledging your help, while still pointing to my answer? Do I mark you as correct?

Comment: Yeah maybe yes because actually after understood your needs, you actually used this approach for depth and inserting. But still point the solution to your answer specifying that strategy was inside that reply and comments. But feel free :) btw, happy that It worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = $(document.getElementById(":nv")).children("br:first").next();
var divToAdd = $("<div></div>").text("Injected Div");

foo.prepend(divToAdd);
```

This should work. One thing to note is that *$(document.getElementById(":nv"))* is faster than *$("\\:nv")* but you can access the element using either method.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to inject the text as the last div BEFORE the signature. This seems to put the new div at the top of the email.